# Secrets pip not downloading MacOS

Tags: python, macos, command-line, pip

the secrets library is not downloading when I try to install the pip. My python is updated to 3.11.0. Wondering if that may be the issue?

```
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/private/var/folders/bb/30cx945s3g9ftgw4q18zyw900000gn/T/pip-install-ll7ks8fq/secrets_1a6d2e6558c34836a716331c20614163/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
          import OpenSSL
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenSSL'
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/bb/30cx945s3g9ftgw4q18zyw900000gn/T/pip-install-ll7ks8fq/secrets_1a6d2e6558c34836a716331c20614163/setup.py", line 12, in <module>
          raise ImportError('Installing this module requires OpenSSL python bindings')
      ImportError: Installing this module requires OpenSSL python bindings
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

The last note leads me to believe that it is to do with the library itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A the error mentions: `ImportError: Installing this module requires OpenSSL python bindings`, you are probably missing OpenSSL bindings. They are part of the `cryptography` package.

Install them with `pip install cryptography` and try again.

EDIT: Python 3.11 is like a few days old. If it does not work you can also try to downscale to 3.10 or 3.9 as the packages is probably not supported yet in 3.11.

Comment: Awesome, the cryptography library downloaded w/o a problem. Appreciate you!